Differences between Caching using serviceWorker (PWA) and Laravel Cache::put()
Caching is a fundamental aspect of optimizing web applications for speed and efficiency. so it's critical to decide the best method and strategy in order to use it. as far as I'm concerned both of them (serviceworker & laravel cashing) use the HTTP Caching to cache something on the localStorage.

My question is:


Which method uses fewer resources?
Which one is an effective way for caching?
In which scenario is it recommended to use Redis for caching?

from my perspective, the service worker is a better option when you have static content that hardly ever gets updated. but why do people use Redis and can the serviceworker be known as clientside caching and the Cacheing from Laravel as server side caching?

the service worker will cache things on the end user's browser. Laravel caching on the other hand can potentially cache content for all users that might request it. Not all content is cacheable for all users though so it really depends on your specific data. Also caching something on the user's browser may be a burden that not all users would be happy with (e.g. maybe they are using an old phone with limited resources and don't like the extra battery drain). There's generally no one correct answer to this

thanks for sharing, my main goal is to know which one is fit to which use cases, and what are each one advantages

Based on my experience, Service Worker uses fewer resources from the server, but Laravel Caching, on the contrary, consumes more resources because it is on the server side.
I think using Service Worker to cache photos, CSS, and JS files and Laravel Caching to cache queries is better.
Redis is also used to cache data that rarely changes, and instead of doing a repeated query every time, you save it inside Redis because it has a high speed.

so people use Redis to cache database queries on the server while service worker are for caching content on the user. so they both are completely different and not the same at all, redis cache queries on server and service worker cache content on the client side

Of course, you can use Redis to cache queries, but if your query is accompanied by pagination, using Redis is not a good option at all.

there are many different cache layers and it will depend and your use case, most of the time you can use several layers together to reduce costs and speed up application responsiveness.
You can cache information in the Client Side, the most common strategies are:

Browser Cache
LocalStorage
IndexedDB
Service Workers
Session Storage
....

You can cache information in a CDN before the request lands into your servers,  this special useful when your server will always answer the request with the same result, like when resolving an image or an api call for things calculated stuff like 2+2=4 you can find more information searching by,

CDN Static Content Caching
CDN Dynamic Content Caching

You can cache information in your Server Application using In-Memory cache: this is specially useful when you have to cache information for the same Request Life Cycle.

This particularly changes a lot depending the platform and framework you are using, but you will use in-memory cache when for example your application has to access multiple times the same resource during the same request lifecycle.

You can cache information in your Server / Infrastructure: This is the most used cache strategy in the server side, specially as the cache layer scales with your infrastructure as you can have multiple servers accessing the same cached resources. In PHP Specifically you these are the most common used mechanism:

File System
Memcached,
Redis
MongoDB...

I'll stop there as you have more than enough to start investigating.
Answer to your questions:

In which scenario is it recommended to use Redis for caching?

Redis is a tool that scale well, it is generally used when you need high availability and performance in a distributed system that is deployed cross avaialability zones and regions.

Which method uses fewer resources?

Web Worker will use your client resources, how much resources will depend on the amount of information that you are caching and what you are doing to create and destroy the cache, your client will pay for this.
Laravel Cache will use your infrastructure for Caching and it will depend again what strategy you use, you will pay for this.
Comparing one vs the other does not make much sense, as explained before these cache mechanism are different and cover different use cases.

Which one is an effective way for caching?

Totally depends on your use case:

If you have things like images that you can cache in your client browser, use Browser Cache

If you have to resolve static content you use CDN Static Content Caching

If you have request that are likely to produce a unique output for your client and that client only, that data is not likely to change you can cache that data in the client side

If you want a Event Based PWA you can certainly use a combination if IndexedDB / localStorage + Web Workers + Socket connection

If you have a request that is likely to produce a Unique Dynamic Server response based that is always the same when the same params are given you can use Dynamic Content Caching

If you have a Third Party Request that is required during a Calculation that needs to happen every time that people is calling your APIs you can use A caching strategy like Redis to capture the third party response or pre-calculated data

If you have to access the same resource multiple times during the same Server request life-cycle you can use In-memory cache

You can certainly use multiple cache layers


Hope this helps to clarify a bit, Still consider taking on additional resources and reading more about the mentioned caching strategies.

thanks a lot for your helpful tips. personally, I had the wrong understanding about caching in the server side, but you completely changed that
